# How do I return a response body for a ring route from within a (try) expression?

Tags: clojure, compojure, ring

I can't figure out where I'm going wrong with the following route:

```
(ns mds.routes.api
 (:require [mds.db.core :refer [*db*] :as db]
            [compojure.core :refer [defroutes POST]]
            [ring.util.http-response :as response]
            [clojure.walk :as walk]))

(defroutes api-routes
  (POST "/student" request
       (let [{body :body} request]
         (let [student (walk/keywordize-keys body)]
           (try
             (db/create-student! student)
             {:saved true
              :error nil
              :student student}
             (catch Exception e  {:saved false
                                    :error e
                                    :student nil})
             )))))
```

I'm trying to return a response body with a json object that looks something like:

```
{
    "saved":"true",
    "error":"nil",
    "student": {...}
}
```

But I'm just getting empty response bodies.  The `db/create-student!` call works fine, and w/o the (try) expression I get either the JSON body or a 500 error, but with the (try) expression I get an empty status 200 response every time.

How do I get the (try) expression to return the map and pass it up to the response handler?

Comment: could you include the code without the `try` as well to see if there is some other difference?

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to guess what could be causing the empty responses with the try in place unless some exception is being thrown due to some other reason. Perhaps there is a difference between what's running and what's in the source file because of some typo or a renamed function. One thing to consider is that exceptions can be thrown further up the middleware stack as well as in the handler.

If you have this wrapped in middleware that converts the responses from clojure datastructures (.edn) to json, that middleware might be throwing an exception trying to serialize an exception. in this case `e`. try this as a test:

```
(defroutes api-routes
  (POST "/student" request
        (let [{body :body} request
              student (walk/keywordize-keys body)]
          (try
            (db/create-student! student)
            {:saved true
             :error nil
             :student student}
            (catch Exception e {:saved false
                                :error (.getMessage e)
                                :student nil})))))
```

and check the output/logs/nrepl-buffer for exceptions about exceptions being thrown while generating the response in the catch expression.

if you don't have any json-response forming middleware elsewhere then try something like this:

```
(defroutes api-routes
  (POST "/student" request
        (let [{body :body} request
              student (walk/keywordize-keys body)]
          (try
            (db/create-student! student)

            {:status 200
             :body (str {:saved true
                         :error nil
                         :student student})}
            (catch Exception e {:status 401
                                :body (str {:saved false
                                            :error (.getMessage e)
                                            :student nil})})))))
```

where you set the response code explicitly and see if you can figure out whats going on.

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping the whole code with `Exception` class it bad practice because it's too wide case. It prevents you from seeing really important errors such as missing files, wrong configuration, invalid arguments and other architectural errors.

But if you really need to catch all the exceptions, at least you may either print or return a stack trace to see what's going on:

```
(ns foo
  (require [clojure.stacktrace :as trace]))

...

;; your handler goes here
(let [trace-string (with-out-str
                     (trace/print-throwable e))]
  {:status 500
   :body trace-string})
```

where `e` is your exception instance.